# Convert RcppArmadillo vector to Rcpp vector

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to convert RcppArmadillo vector (e.g. `arma::colvec`) to a Rcpp vector (`NumericVector`). I know I can first convert `arma::colvec` to `SEXP` and then convert `SEXP` to `NumericVector` (e.g. `as<NumericVector>(wrap(temp)`), assuming temp is an `arma::colvec` object). But what is a good way to do that?

I want to do that simply because I am unsure if it is okay to pass `arma::colvec` object as a parameter to an `Rcpp::Function` object.

Comment: what happened when you tried it ? Trying something is a good way of testing if if works and when it does not work, often the compiler tells you why.

Comment: And if and when it works, you could even time it and compare different ways of doing it...

Comment: 'as<NumericVector>(wrap(temp)' has been the way that I used. It is compiled without any error and returns correct answer. But recently, when I put my function to a unix cluster for running big simulation. I encounter some errors like:

Comment: Sorry I mistyped an enter and passed the 5 mins for editing... My comments continue as: I encounter some errors like:'Rcpp::eval_error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): unused argument(s) (error = function (e)', 'Rcpp::eval_error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?', ... My entire program performs deterministic job, but when I reran the exact same codes without the above error. So it confuses me. 'as<NumericVector>(wrap(temp)' is the part that I am curious if I am right to do that.

Comment: What versions of R, Rcpp and RcppArmadillo are installed on the cluster?

Comment: R (2.15.2), Rcpp (0.10.2) and RcppArmadillo (0.3.6.1). I also found that the problem seems to only occur for those R sessions started in the slave node through slurm.

Comment: Almost surely due to slurm invoking different versions.

Answer (score 9):

I was trying to Evaluate a `Rcpp::Function` with argument `arma::vec`, it seems that it takes the argument in four forms without compilation errors. That is, if `f` is a `Rcpp::Function` and `a` is a `arma::vec`, then

1. `f(a)`
2. `f(wrap(a))`
3. `f(as<NumericVector>(wrap(a)))`
4. `f(NumericVector(a.begin(),a.end()))`

produce no compilation and runtime errors, at least apparently.

For this reason, I have conducted a little test for the four versions of arguments. Since I suspect that somethings will go wrong in garbage collection, I test them again  `gctorture`.

```
gctorture(on=FALSE)
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = '
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double foo1(arma::vec a, arma::vec b, Function f){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        sum += as<double>(f(a, b));
    }
    return sum;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double foo2(arma::vec a, arma::vec b, Function f){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        sum += as<double>(f(wrap(a),wrap(b)));
    }
    return sum;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double foo3(arma::vec a, arma::vec b, Function f){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        sum += as<double>(f(as<NumericVector>(wrap(a)),as<NumericVector>(wrap(b))));
    }
    return sum;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double foo4(arma::vec a, arma::vec b, Function f){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        sum += as<double>(f(NumericVector(a.begin(),a.end()),NumericVector(b.begin(),b.end())));
    }
    return sum;
}
')
# note that when gctorture is on, the program will be very slow as it
# tries to perfrom GC for every allocation.
# gctorture(on=TRUE)
f = function(x,y) {
    mean(x) + mean(y)
}
# all three functions should return 700
foo1(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # error
foo2(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # wrong answer (occasionally)!
foo3(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # correct answer
foo4(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # correct answer
```

As a result, the first method produces an error, the second method produces a wrong answer and only the third and the fourth method return the correct answer.

```
> # they should return 700
> foo1(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # error
Error: invalid multibyte string at '<80><a1><e2>'
> foo2(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # wrong answer (occasionally)!
[1] 712
> foo3(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # correct answer
[1] 700
> foo4(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # correct answer
[1] 700
```

Note that, if `gctorture` is set `FALSE`, then all functions will return a correct result.

```
> foo1(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # error
[1] 700
> foo2(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # wrong answer (occasionally)!
[1] 700
> foo3(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # correct answer
[1] 700
> foo4(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f) # correct answer
[1] 700
```

It means that method 1 and method 2 are subjected to break when garbage is collected during runtime and we don't know when it happens. Thus, it is **dangerous** to not wrap the parameter properly.

**Edit**: as of 2017-12-05, all four conversions produce the correct result.

1. `f(a)`
2. `f(wrap(a))`
3. `f(as<NumericVector>(wrap(a)))`
4. `f(NumericVector(a.begin(),a.end()))`

and this is the benchmark

```
> microbenchmark(foo1(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f), foo2(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f), foo
3(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f), foo4(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), f))
Unit: milliseconds
                            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq
 foo1(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6), f) 2.575459 2.694297 2.905398 2.734009 2.921552
 foo2(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6), f) 2.574565 2.677380 2.880511 2.731615 2.847573
 foo3(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6), f) 2.582574 2.701779 2.862598 2.753256 2.875745
 foo4(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6), f) 2.378309 2.469361 2.675188 2.538140 2.695720
      max neval
 4.186352   100
 5.336418   100
 4.611379   100
 3.734019   100
```

And `f(NumericVector(a.begin(),a.end()))` is marginally faster than other methods.

Comment: Let's just think this through for a second. You are using `eval()` to let R evaluate an object managed by Armadillo data structures, and you are relying on implicit conversion. I would at a minimum explicitly pass from Armadillo data structure to Rcpp data structures. Besides, `eval()` is a very last resort which is almost more or less foregoing the gains of operating in C++ in the first place.

Comment: It is true that writing a R function and passing it to Rcpp performs much worse than writing a c function. But it is sometimes necessary to allow user defined functions, an example would be approximating first derivative of a given function.

Comment: I appreciate that you agree that it is a bad idea that ought to be avoided. Now on to my second point: if you really think you must call R from C(++), do it with an R data structure.

Answer (score 6):

This should works with `arma::vec`, `arma::rowvec` and `arma::colvec`:

```
template <typename T>
Rcpp::NumericVector arma2vec(const T& x) {
    return Rcpp::NumericVector(x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. I used wrap to do the conversion at the core of several layers of for loops and it was very slow. I think the wrap function is to blame for dragging the speed down so I wish to know if there is an elegant way to do this.

As for Raymond's question, you might want to try including the namespace like: `Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(wrap(A))` instead or include a line `using namespace Rcpp;` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: Reproducible example, or it doesn't exist.  Are you sure the slowness is not from you calling Rcpp::Function repeatedly?