# Why do I get the error for using "pnorm" in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I need to involve variable from `arma::`in my Rcpp code. But I ran into a problem when trying to use the sugar function `pnorm`. Here is a demo:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double pget(NumericVector x, NumericVector beta) {
  arma::colvec xx = Rcpp::as<arma::colvec>(x) ;
  arma::colvec bb = Rcpp::as<arma::colvec>(beta) ;
  double tt = as_scalar( arma::trans(xx) * bb);
  double temp = Rcpp::pnorm(tt);
  return temp;
}
```

Then I got an error: `no matching function for call to 'pnorm5'`

Does that mean I cannot use `Rcpp::pnorm`???

Comment: This almost surely is a duplicate a few times over but I don't have time to dig now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Rcpp` sugar functions are meant for vector type arguments like `Rcpp::NumericVector`. For scalar arguments you can use the functions in the `R` namespace:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double pget(NumericVector x, NumericVector beta) {
  arma::colvec xx = Rcpp::as<arma::colvec>(x) ;
  arma::colvec bb = Rcpp::as<arma::colvec>(beta) ;
  double tt = as_scalar( arma::trans(xx) * bb);
  double temp = R::pnorm(tt, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 0);
  return temp;
}

/*** R
x <- rnorm(5)
beta <- rnorm(5)
pget(x, beta)
*/
```

BTW, here two variants. First variant uses `arma` instead of `Rcpp` vectors as arguments. Since these are `const` references, no data is copied. In addition, `arma::dot` is used:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double pget2(const arma::colvec& xx, const arma::colvec& bb) {
  double tt = arma::dot(xx, bb);
  return R::pnorm(tt, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 0);
}
```

The second variant calculates the scalar product without resorting to Armadillo:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double pget3(NumericVector x, NumericVector beta) {
  double tt = Rcpp::sum(x * beta);
  return R::pnorm(tt, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will `Rcpp::pnorm` be faster than `R::pnorm` if I do vectorization?

Comment: Great answer (+1) in terms of getting down to OP's problem, but a note on your posted code: You have the order of arguments mixed up a little. You want `R::pnorm(tt, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 0)` rather than `R::pnorm(tt, 1.0, 0.0, 1, 0)` (mean comes before sd).

Comment: @lostintheforest How about benchmarking the two functions?

Comment: isn't  `as_scalar(arma::trans(xx) * bb)` equivalent to the much shorter `dot(xx,bb)` ?  ([documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#dot))

Comment: @mtall Indeed, thanks for the reminder. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm much less of an expert than @RalfStubner at Rcpp, so I had to hack around (with help from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253069/convert-rcpparmadillo-vector-to-rcpp-vector) and the [Rcpp cheat sheat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-quickref.pdf)) to get the following code.  Instead of using the R-namespace versions on scalars, I converted back to a `NumericVector` ... this can almost certainly be done more efficiently/skipping a few steps by someone who actually knows what they're doing ... e.g. it's possible that the arma-to-NumericVector conversion could be done directly without going through `as_scalar` ... ?

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector pget(NumericVector x, NumericVector beta) {
  colvec xx = as<colvec>(x) ;
  colvec bb = as<colvec>(beta) ;
  double tt = as_scalar(trans(xx) * bb);
  NumericVector tt2 = NumericVector::create( tt );
  NumericVector temp = Rcpp::pnorm(tt2);
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: The `arma` to `NumericVector` conversion can be done without going through `as_scalar()`, like this: `NumericVector tt = as<NumericVector>(wrap(arma::trans(xx) * bb));`, but I haven't benchmarked to see if it's efficient